# Change the background image randomly on mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, mouseevent

change the background image on mouse hover like facebook album .when you hover the any album you have perview 3 4 image randomly.how can i do this in jquery. i try this but its not work as i want to do

```
function randomPick(arr) {

var selected = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)]

return selected;
}


images =
[

"image1.png",
"image2.png",
"image3.png",
"image4.png",
"image5.png"
]



function randomHover () {

var myImage = document.getElementById('hover');
var selImage = randomPick(images);

myImage.src = selImage;


}

function resetState() {

var myImage = document.getElementById('hover');
myImage.src = "something.png";

}
```

Comment: do you always get image at index 0?

Comment: yes i am  getting image at index 0

Answer (score 0):

try converting the return value to an integer like this:

```
arr[parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length))]
```